# catching Exceeded maximum execution time?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there anyway of catching this GAS error: "Exceeded maximum execution time"

I mean catching with try ... catch(e) // so far it's not working for me.

Thanks

Comment: not sure how you could - you've gone over the limit. allowing more code to execute in the catch block would only allow people to bypass the limit and run without ANY limits.

Answer (score 2):

As written in the comments to your question, thats not possible. But, however, you can set a flag in scriptDB or properties when execution starts and clear that flag when execution comes to a normal end, so you can find out during the next run wether your script came to a regular end when it was run last time and try to take corrective actions if not.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is correct; it's not possible. An easy alternative to the workaround that pbhd mentioned would be to simply track the runtime of your script (e.g. comparing results of `new Date().getTime()` at regular intervals) and run whatever you'd include under your `catch` statement right before you hit the maximum execution time. The maximum is 6 minutes ([reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)).

That way, you don't have to catch the error -- you can preempt it.

Answer (score -4):

During normal testing, it is possible to accidentally create an infinite (or very long running) loop that consumes the daily execution time limit 100%.

Even if you realize what you have dome wrong **immediately**, you cannot immediately re-try with Google scripts *for another 24 hours* - thus slowing down ongoing development significantly and maybe forcing the developer to do some other work , taking his focus/"attention stream"  away from the current problem. This is almost always bad.

My product ("IBM OLIVER CICS test/debug" - see [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_OLIVER_%28CICS_interactive_test/debug%29)) solved this problem - and many others - around 37 years ago - by having a time limit on any *particular* transaction and intercepting the resulting time out, allowing options of:-

1. continuation or
2. examine/modify variables
3. "manual" re-try (for the same time) or
4. abort.

Google could implement this approach just as easily - by "pausing" if execution time is looking too heavy. I had a similar solution to other resources in OLIVER - such as excessive API calls ("possible macro loop") and excessive memory usage.

It seems it takes an "old timer" like me to provide solutions to problems that have existed "since the beginning of time" (and certainly before PC's were thought of).

Googles current "solution" (i.e. absolute limits) only helps Google keep its own servers from being swamped. It would be easy for them to do what OLIVER did all those years ago. By the way there should be no "IBM" prefix on the Wikipedia article - it was my own product and some clown Wikipedia editor altered it to include the prefix.

(By the way, Google do not prevent other scripts on same s/s running - that maybe only use *minimal* amounts of extra time ( i.e. Scripts on the same spreadsheet still work) . I tried renaming the original script as an experiment but it was stopped after a very short time with "exceeded execution time" error.

GIZ-A-JOB Google - you know its worth it!

Comment: I don't get this answer. Seems like bragging to me. -1